# I'm trying to make a 'topcoins' command to see the richest rich players using the application - database used (wio.db)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

> I want to pull **"kwanzas"** from all users and create a rank of the 20 richest users and see the position in which the author is

> Way I use in my code to fetch something in my .json file

```js
client.userdb.get(`usuario.'id'.economia.kwanzas`)
```

meu código

````js
{
    "usuario": {
        "982405935404285962": {
            "economia": {
                "kwanzas": 20000,
                "banco": -20000,
                "trabalho": 1661702099111,
                "aposta": false,
                "roubo": 1661712130044
            },
            "nome": "vk 7vvch#0007",
            "xp": {
                "xp": 24,
                "max": 50,
                "level": 1
            }
        },
        "992935083231150231": {
            "economia": {
                "kwanzas": 115139,
                "banco": 0,
                "aposta": false
            },
            "nome": "krozz#0007",
            "xp": {
                "xp": 22
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: map and sort, there's like 10000 of the same questions on here that a simple google search would answer